# javascript need help in highlight across tags text in html

Tags: javascript, regex, tags, match, highlight

check my demo i have html text:

```
<div id="test">this is <a href="#">my</a> <span>nice</span> <span> cool</span> text that needs highlighting my nice <span>cool</span> text</div>
```

i saw an example of how to highlight string across html tags which works but partially if i search only for two words its will work but if search more than two words it only highlight first word and last word as this demo :

```js
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var term = "my nice cool text";
//term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*");
term = term.split(' ').join('(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*')
//alert(term);
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*|)((<[^>]+>)+|[\\r\\n\\s]+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

$("#test").html(src_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">this is <a href="#">my</a> <span>nice</span> <span> cool</span> text that needs highlighting my nice <span>cool</span> text</div>
```

as you can see the first string "nice cool" which include html tags not highlighted the second works there something in the last regex i couldn't  solve it any help plz thanks..

### **solution:**

i found i crazy way but i'm not sure how it's work but its working anyway here is the demo :

```js
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var term = "my nice cool top text";
//term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*");
term = term.split(' ').join('(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*')
//alert(term);
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<span class=hit>$1</span>");
//alert(src_str);
src_str = src_str.replace(/(<span class=hit>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+|[\\r\\n\\s]+)([^<>]*<\/span>|(<[^>]+>|[\\s]+)*)/,"$1</span>$2<span class=hit>$3$4");

$("#test").html(src_str);
```

```css
.hit{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">this is <div>

<a href="#"><br>my<br></a><span>
<br>
nice</span> <span> <br>cool<div>top</div></span> text that needs highlighting my nice <span>cool top</span> text</div>

</div>
```

### **better solution:**

```js
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var term = "my nice cool text";
//term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*");
term = term.split(' ').join('(<[^>]+>|[\\r\\n\\s]+)*')
//alert(term);
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(pattern, function(match){
var re = /(^|[>])(?![^<]*?<\/y)(.*?)([<]|$)/gi; 
match = match.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"");

match = match.replace(re, function (m,g1,g2,g3) {
  return g1+"<b class='hit' style='color:black'>"+g2+"</b>"+g3;
});
//alert(match);
return match;
});
```

```css
.hit{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">this is <a href="#">my</a> <span>nice</span> <span> cool</span> text that needs highlighting my nice <span>cool</span> text</div>
```

there is library some one found solution that works in old browser i think you can check it:

https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem for all situations, but this should work in this particular case:

```js
var src_str = $("#test").text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); //remove more than 1 space
var term = "my nice cool text";

var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");

$("#test").html(src_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">this is <a href="#">my</a> <span>nice</span> <span> cool</span> text that needs highlighting my nice <span>cool</span> text</div>
```

Comment: but i don't want change the original HTML text in the document but thanks it's another way ...

Comment: Problem is that this removes html tags in the text.